# pipe whole script to file and terminal

Tags: bash

i want a 1liner to pipe to file AND terminal at the same time(write 1 command, then all other commands are shown like normal in terminal, but output, preferably but not required : command name, to be appended to a file)
, i know exec does this:

```
exec > /vga/log/$(date +'%Y%m%d.%H%M%S').txt
ls
```

but now i cant see anything in the terminal, how can i add tee to the above so that it works, ive tried

```
exec > tee /vga/log/$(date +'%Y%m%d.%H%M%S').txt
ls
# creates a file called 'tee' with output, nothing in terminal

exec | tee /vga/log/$(date +'%Y%m%d.%H%M%S').txt
ls
# creates file uninst_total_20150729.161010.txt but is empty, terminal is ok
```

-- solution

```
#!/bin/bash
exec 1> >(tee -a /vga/log/$(date +'%Y%m%d.%H%M%S').txt)
exec 2>&1
ls
```

Comment: There is a specific utility for this kind of job names `script` ..check `man script` ..which will also preserve the PAGER behavior for multi page output..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you search is that:

```
exec 1> >(tee -a $LOGFILE)
```

Every data that is send trough channel 1 (stdout) is redirected line by line to `tee` which appends `-a` it to a file AND prints it to the stdout.

If you want to redirect both, stdout and stderr, use this after the first `exec` statement from above:

```
exec 2>&1
```

Comment: There is a problem though..Configured pager behaviors will be lost for multi-page outputs..

Comment: @heemayl Do you mean the pager of `man` for example? If yes, that's not relevant here, because the question says it's a script. A pager will not appear in a script.

Answer (score 1):

Using `script`

1. Start the command `script`
2. Make your activities
3. Stop `script` via <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>D</kbd>
4. See the output in `typescript`

*Example*

```
% script
% ls -og
total 72
-rw-rw-r-- 1   0 Jul 24 15:11 e
-rw-rw-r-- 1  43 Jul 29 12:54 File1
-rw-rw-r-- 1  26 Jul 29 09:07 File2
-rwxrwxr-x 1 557 Jul 29 09:02 foo
-rw-rw-r-- 1  23 Jul 29 15:33 out
-rw-rw-r-- 1   0 Jul 29 15:32 test
-rw-rw-r-- 1   0 Jul 29 16:01 typescript
```

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>D</kbd>

```
% 
Script started, file is typescript
                                  Script started, file is typescript
Script done, file is typescript

% cat typescript 
Script started on Mi 29 Jul 2015 16:01:31 CEST
% ls -og
total 72
-rw-rw-r-- 1   0 Jul 24 15:11 e
-rw-rw-r-- 1  43 Jul 29 12:54 File1
-rw-rw-r-- 1  26 Jul 29 09:07 File2
-rwxrwxr-x 1 557 Jul 29 09:02 foo
-rw-rw-r-- 1  23 Jul 29 15:33 out
-rw-rw-r-- 1   0 Jul 29 15:32 test
-rw-rw-r-- 1   0 Jul 29 16:01 typescript
[aboettger:~/tmp] % 

Script done on Mi 29 Jul 2015 16:01:39 CEST
```

---

Using `tee`

```
<your_command> | tee -a out
```

---

From `man tee`

```
-a, --append
      append to the given FILEs, do not overwrite
```

---

*Example*

```
$ ls -ogla | tee -a out
total 80
drwxrwxr-x  2  4096 Jul 29 15:29 .
drwx------ 52 20480 Jul 29 15:26 ..
-rw-rw-r--  1     0 Jul 24 15:11 e
-rw-rw-r--  1    43 Jul 29 12:54 File1
-rw-rw-r--  1    26 Jul 29 09:07 File2
-rwxrwxr-x  1   557 Jul 29 09:02 foo
-rw-rw-r--  1     0 Jul 29 15:29 out

$ cat out
total 80
drwxrwxr-x  2  4096 Jul 29 15:29 .
drwx------ 52 20480 Jul 29 15:26 ..
-rw-rw-r--  1     0 Jul 24 15:11 e
-rw-rw-r--  1    43 Jul 29 12:54 File1
-rw-rw-r--  1    26 Jul 29 09:07 File2
-rwxrwxr-x  1   557 Jul 29 09:02 foo
-rw-rw-r--  1     0 Jul 29 15:29 out
```

Comment: This is appending to both stdout and out file?

Comment: Of course. See my examples.